# Is having multiple websites a good idea or a bad one for SEO?

Tags: seo, multiple-domains

I am in charge of my companies website and one of my tasks is to improve SEO. Granted, I am new to this and have been researching for the past 6 months and had an idea. My plan is to build multiple websites and create a huge site using multiple domains. We offer different services and our main home page will have all of the services with links to the other websites which are the individual services so that I don't have to worry about duplicate page content.

Example:

`www.companyname.com` is the main site

`www.service#1.com` is one of our services

`www.service#2.com` is another one of our services etc.

Will this have an affect on our SEO in a positive way like I think or would it impact us negatively? and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having different websites for different services won’t affect you negatively but it won’t give you any special SEO benefits. According to me it’s a waste of time. Having different websites will block your visitors to see your other services which will be a loss of advantage for your website and for your company. It will limit your visitors. If you have a single website with all your services as different pages it will give SEO weight to your website as **Zistoloen** said in his [answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/59860/28169).  If someone searched your company name he/she can easily identify all your services at a single place which will be user friendly.

Comment: What if i set up each site to look the same but instead of internal links it used external links and the user would think they were in the same site unless they looked at the URL? wouldn't that add to backlinks and grow each site as far as ranks go? it wouldn't affect the user experience because they will be able to navigate to all site as if it was one website.

Comment: If you create more websites and cross liked each sites means it will look like you are following [Link Farming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_farm) method which is a old technique as well as a bad technique in SEO. It may harm your website. Source http://searchengineland.com/googles-matt-cutts-linking-20-domains-together-likely-a-cross-linking-scheme-167089

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's not really a good idea. It will be better to speak about your services in the same website.

It's better for users because you centralize all information about your company in the same place. It's better for SEO because you increase the number of pages in the main site. Therefore, you give SEO weight to it. It's win win for your company.

Comment: with that in mind, what is better, a site with fully relatable content or a site with multiple sections of different content? I ask because everything I know about SEO i have searched for online and pretty much found the same information. it seems very vague and easy. as long as i have unique content and change the content on my page frequently i should start ranking high but after the past year i have seen very little improvement.

Comment: You need to always create interesting content for users (it's a requirement for rank higher). The best site ever is a site which has a lot of new interesting content and updated pages. And if you can, keep the same theme for all your website.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think i have my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you link them together Google might view your other websites as cosmetic websites designed just to create backlinks to your website (since that's the backbone of SEO) and if it does it will penalize you and thus hurt your SEO.